# Index was outside the bounds of the array in calling WCF API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, api

I have developed a web application with ASP.net(C#, .Net Framework 4.0) in some part of the application I am calling an API to get some information. I noticed that some of the calls to API are failed and I got this error:

> **Index was outside the bounds of the array.**

when I checked the stack trace I saw this :

> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
>
> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2.set_Item(TKey key, TValue
>   value)
>
> at Navitaire.Ncl.Validation.ValidationManager.getValidationAttributes(MemberInfo mi, Boolean& skip)
>
> at Navitaire.Ncl.Validation.ValidationManager.validate(Object declaringObject, Object value, MemberInfo mi, List1 results)
>
> at Navitaire.Ncl.Validation.ValidationManager.Validate(Object obj)
>
> at Navitaire.Ncl.ServiceModel.ParameterValidationInspector.BeforeCall(String operationName, Object[] inputs)
>
> at Navitaire.Ncl.ServiceModel.Remoting.BoilerplateSinkBase.InvokeBeforeCallInspectors(StateData stateData, RemotingMessage& message)
>
> at Navitaire.Ncl.ServiceModel.Remoting.BoilerplateServerSink.ProcessMessage(IServerChannelSinkStacksinkStack, IMessage requestMsg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, IMessage& responseMsg, ITransportHeaders&
>    responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)
>
> at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryServerFormatterSink.ProcessMessage(IServerChannelSinkStack sinkStack, IMessage requestMsg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, IMessage& responseMsg, ITransportHeaders&
>    responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)

I put a break point on the catch exception part, so every time that I got the error, application will stop and I can read the exception. I noticed that if in this moment I call the API again (move the cursor to the API call line) it works fine. so it means there is no problem with parameter that I am passing to the API.

I tried to run the application on three different environments with totally different network and different internet connection, but still I got the same error.

Can you please someone help me on this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a problem with the API, rather than your code, especially if it works the second time you make the same call.
I believe the API is doing something with an internal dictionary, that doesn't quite get set up correctly the first time you call it, but by the second time, it has been and works "correctly".

Are you able to view / have access to the code for the API method your calling?

**If so,** you are best running that in debug alongside your application, placing a breakpoint on the entry to that method and stepping over the lines within it to see what it is doing and why it may be breaking.
If it's your API, or you're allowed to share the code of this method and you can't find the error yourself, please post up the code of the API method and I'll help you find what the cause could be.

If you are not able to view the code, I would suggest contacting the producer of the API if it's a private one, or if it's an open source API, share the link and provide a code sample of what your code looks like (showing how you make the API call) and we can help diagnose it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. unfortunately I do not have access to the API code but it is a private API and I already asked them to check their code.Do you think it can be because of some connection issue and the error that is returned from the API is not relevant?

Answer (score 0):

I checked with the API developer and I found that there was some thing wrong on their side after they fixed the bug I did not get any error anymore.